# Why is the number of recurrences in the Recurrence Object of an event JSON is always zero?

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

When I make an Outlook Calendar API call, I get a bunch of events, some are recurring and some are not. For recurring events, I strangely see zero number of occurrences under recurrence range sub-object. This happens for every recurring meeting. The definition on Outlook REST API reference says that it indicates the number of occurrences for that specific recurring event. For example:

```
'Recurrence': {
    'Pattern': {
        'FirstDayOfWeek': 'Sunday',
        'Month': 0,
        'DaysOfWeek': ['Monday'],
        'Index': 'First',
        'Type': 'Weekly',
        'Interval': 1,
        'DayOfMonth': 0
    },
    'Range': {
        'EndDate': '2016-06-14',
        'StartDate': '2015-06-01',
        'Type': 'EndDate',
        'RecurrenceTimeZone': 'CentralStandardTime',
        'NumberOfOccurrences': 0
    }
},
```

This is extremely annoying, since now I will have to count the range and divide it by the pattern type. It would have been great if NumberOfOccurrences actually showed the number of occurrences, and on top of that updated based on the recurring event cancellations. I can understand if the end date was in perpetuity, and it would be impossible to compute number of occurrences in that case. But, in the above example, it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @jason-johnston your help is appreciated here as always.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. Let me ask some folks. In the meantime, if you use a calendar view (instead of querying /me/events), you get individual occurrences (basically making the server expand the series for you).

Comment: Ah, it's not always 0, if you create it in Outlook and use the "End after X occurrences" option its returned then, but EndDate is set to "0001-01-01". So my guess is this is just a copy of what the user entered at creation time. I'll verify and then put an actual answer.

Comment: @JasonJohnston you are right, I suppose I can count the individual number of events. I guess it's better that way since I can now see a change in number of recurring events if there is ever a deletion. I understand the real meaning of Number of occurences now. It was an option available for Outlook exchange, but appears to have disappeared for Outlook Live. Since was creating events using Outlook Live, that variable is disabled be default. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Not so much that the field is disabled, there's just no way to set it from OWA (Outlook Live).

Answer (score 0):

The values in the `Range` field are what the user specifies when they create the event's recurrence. Desktop Outlook allows you to specify a specific number of occurrences, where Outlook Web App only allows you to set an end date. So you'll never see this set if you only use OWA to create events ;).

I passed along your question to our engineering folks. I think we could possibly make this better, at least in some cases. I can't promise anything, but they are aware.